# Insert dataset records in different database

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to insert the dataset records(C#) from database SQL Server into the MySQL database table.

I need to do the bulk insertion of records.

I can't export the SQL Server table on txt or csv file, because I don't  authorized to command :

> EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure

How can I do this in C#

Comment: Create 2 connections, one to SQLServer and one to MySQL. Read record, Insert record

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks! do you have any example for me?

Comment: This might help - https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic340912-146-1.aspx